Having Trouble Installing PyBluez2 On PyCharm in Windows
Everytime I try to download PyBluez2 on PyCharm this keeps showing
"Collecting pybluez2
  Using cached pybluez2-0.46.tar.gz (50 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating C:\Users\Samsong\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_l58f7rh\pybluez2.egg-info
      writing C:\Users\Samsong\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_l58f7rh\pybluez2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Samsong\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_l58f7rh\pybluez2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing eager_resources to C:\Users\Samsong\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_l58f7rh\pybluez2.egg-info\eager_resources.txt
      writing top-level names to C:\Users\Samsong\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_l58f7rh\pybluez2.egg-info\top_level.txt
      writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Samsong\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_l58f7rh\pybluez2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      error: package directory 'bluetooth\windows' does not exist
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details."

Anyone know how to fix this?
I have tried to downgrade the python version I was using, I tried to download it via in the application itself in the settings. Nothing has worked. Any Ideas?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. BlueZ is the Linux Bluetooth stack. However, you seem to be running Windows. Installing PyBluez2 on Windows doesn't make sense.
